Property 'required' does not exist on type 'FieldError'. React Hook Form using in TypeScript Page
I am using React Hook Form to validate the input fields. In React.js page it is working great as you could see below in the first screenshot.

But the same code I am trying to use with TypeScript page it is not working. showing errors:
Property 'required' does not exist on type 'FieldError | Merge<FieldError, FieldErrorsImpl> | MultipleFieldErrors'.
Property 'required' does not exist on type 'FieldError'.
Why is it like that?  i am new in TypeScript.

here is the code:
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { GiInfo } from "react-icons/gi";

export default function TestPage() {
    const {register,getValues,formState: { errors },handleSubmit} = useForm({criteriaMode: "all",mode: "onChange"});
    const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);
  return (
   
   
<div className='container mt-5 Validation_From'> 
<div className='bg-light rounded border border-2 p-3 mt-5'> 
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
    <div className='row align-items-center'>
    <div className="col-md-3 position-relative mb-2">

    <label className="form-label">Name</label>
    <input
          className="form-control"
            type="text"
            id="name"
            autoComplete="off" 
            {...register("name", {
              required: true,
              minLength: 2,
              
            })}            
          />

    {errors?.name?.types?.required && <div className='c_validation'><GiInfo/> Please fill out this field. </div>}
    {errors?.name?.types?.minLength && <div className='c_validation'><GiInfo/>Name minLength 2 </div>}


    </div>

    <div className="col-md-3 position-relative mb-2">

    <label className="form-label">Email</label>
    <input
          className="form-control"
            type="text"
            id="email"
            autoComplete="off" 
            {...register("email", {
              required: true,
              pattern: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i
            
            })}
          />


    {errors?.email?.types?.required && <div className='c_validation'><GiInfo/> Please fill out this field. </div>}
    {errors?.email?.types?.pattern && <div className='c_validation'><GiInfo/> Invalid email address </div>}


    </div>

      <div className="col-md-3 position-relative mb-2">

    <label className="form-label">Password</label>
    <input
          className="form-control"
            type="password"
            autoComplete="off" 
            id="password"

            {...register("password", {
              required: true,
              minLength: 10,
              pattern: /\d+/gi
            })}
          />

    {errors?.password?.types?.required && <div className='c_validation'><GiInfo/> Please fill out this field. </div>}
    {errors?.password?.types?.minLength && <div className='c_validation'><GiInfo/> Password minLength 10 </div>}
    {errors?.password?.types?.pattern && <div className='c_validation'><GiInfo/> Password number only </div>}

      </div>

      <div className="col-md-3 position-relative mb-2">

      <label className="form-label">Confirm Password</label>
    <input
          className="form-control"
            type="password"
            autoComplete="off"  
            id="conpassword"

            {...register("conpassword", {
              required: true,
        
              validate: (value) =>
                value === getValues("password")
            })}

            
          />


              
    {errors?.conpassword?.types?.required && <div className='c_validation'><GiInfo/> Please fill out this field. </div>}
    {errors.conpassword && errors.conpassword.type === "validate" && <div className='c_validation'><GiInfo/>Passwords do not match</div>}

      </div>
      
      <div className="col-md-12 position-relative mb-2 text-end">
           <button className="btn btn-primary rounded mt-4">Submit</button>
      </div>
   

      </div>
  </form>
  </div>
</div>


  )
}


This issue is mainly because these properties doesn’t exist on errors?.name.
A way to actively debug this is to use  console.log(errors) or console.log(errors?.name) for each field.
For instance, this is how to show the error in the name field. Check if the name field has an error and then display the message you want to show.
  {errors?.name && <div className='c_validation'><GiInfo/>Name minLength 2, Please fill out this field. </div>}

import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { GiInfo } from "react-icons/gi";

export default function TestPage() {
    const {register,getValues,formState: { errors },handleSubmit} = useForm({criteriaMode: "all",mode: "onChange"});
    const onSubmit = (data) => console.log(data);
  return (
   
   
<div className='container mt-5 Validation_From'> 
<div className='bg-light rounded border border-2 p-3 mt-5'> 
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
    <div className='row align-items-center'>
    <div className="col-md-3 position-relative mb-2">

    <label className="form-label">Name</label>
    <input
          className="form-control"
            type="text"
            id="name"
            autoComplete="off" 
            {...register("name", {
              required: true,
              minLength: 2,
              
            })}            
          />

    {errors?.name && <div className='c_validation'><GiInfo/>Name minLength 2, Please fill out this field. </div>}


    </div>

    <div className="col-md-3 position-relative mb-2">

    <label className="form-label">Email</label>
    <input
          className="form-control"
            type="text"
            id="email"
            autoComplete="off" 
            {...register("email", {
              required: true,
              pattern: /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,}$/i
            
            })}
          />


    {errors?.email && <div className='c_validation'><GiInfo/> Invalid email address </div>}
 


    </div>

      <div className="col-md-3 position-relative mb-2">

    <label className="form-label">Password</label>
    <input
          className="form-control"
            type="password"
            autoComplete="off" 
            id="password"

            {...register("password", {
              required: true,
              minLength: 10,
              pattern: /\d+/gi
            })}
          />

    {errors?.password && <div className='c_validation'><GiInfo/> Password number only, Password minLength 10 </div>}

      </div>

      <div className="col-md-3 position-relative mb-2">

      <label className="form-label">Confirm Password</label>
    <input
          className="form-control"
            type="password"
            autoComplete="off"  
            id="conpassword"

            {...register("conpassword", {
              required: true,
        
              validate: (value) =>
                value === getValues("password")
            })}

            
          />


              
    {errors?.conpassword && <div className='c_validation'><GiInfo/> Please fill out this field. </div>}
    {errors.conpassword && errors.conpassword.type === "validate" && <div className='c_validation'><GiInfo/>Passwords do not match</div>}

      </div>
      
      <div className="col-md-12 position-relative mb-2 text-end">
           <button className="btn btn-primary rounded mt-4">Submit</button>
      </div>
   

      </div>
  </form>
  </div>
</div>


  )
}


